# Azure Container Instance ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, rest

I have deployed my container from azure container registry and my ACI is running, I can also see that the REST service of Springboot application has started, however I am not able to send my request to the ACI from Postman, always returns ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. My ACI also has a public IP

Comment: Did you should specify --port parameter? Then it will be up and running on public IP address.

Comment: I did, still did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deployed my REST app as a ContainerApp in Azure to resolve the issue